# JDBC Kafka Connect with DB2

Tags: jdbc, db2, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I'm struggling to get Confluent's kafka connector to connect to DB2.

I am running an ubuntu instance inside docker for testing pruposes. The solution needs to be deployed to kubernetes, so docker it is.

I have installed the Confluent platform using apt-get and adding their repos. All services are running, kafka, zookeeper, schema and kafka rest.

I have created my kafka connect properties file as described in this article: https://www.progress.com/blogs/build-an-etl-pipeline-with-kafka-connect-via-jdbc-connectors

I assumed that this will work the same for DB2. The step I'm missing in the above tutorial is this one:
`java -jar PROGRESS_DATADIRECT_JDBC_POSTGRESQL_ALL.jar`

I tried to run it like this:
`java -jar /usr/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc/db2jcc.jar`

I get this error:
`no main manifest attribute, in /usr/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc/db2jcc.jar`

I proceeded anyway, but of course I get an error:
`No suitable driver found for jdbc:datadirect:db2://db2-server:50000;User=db2admin;Password=pwd;Database=test_db`

This is my command to start the connector:
`/usr/bin/connect-standalone /etc/kafka/connect-standalone.properties /etc/kafka-connect-jdbc/db2.properties`

This is my properties file:

```
name=test-db2-jdbc
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
tasks.max=1
 connection.url=jdbc:datadirect:db2://db2-server:50000;User=db2admin;Password=pwd;Database=test_db
mode=timestamp+incrementing
incrementing.column.name=id
timestamp.column.name=modified_time
topic.prefix=test_jdbc_
table.whitelist=data_log
```

I am sure I'm close. I just need to get the DB2 driver to register inside java or for kafka connect to pick it up and be able to use it.

I have tried other values for `connector.class`, but if I change that to the name of the class as it would be in other Java apps, I get this error:
`java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Class com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Jcc does not implement Connector`

Any help or suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Your question shows you are trying to use a datdirect driver for Db2 (instead of an IBM supplied driver for Db2). Have you installed that datadirect driver in the container and proved it works outside of Confluence/kafka?

Comment: Hello. No I have not tried it outside of confluence/ Kafka. Thanks for that tip. I should have thought of that! Trying that now.

Comment: I'm not super-familiar with Java, but I see we do use these JAR files inside sqoop, where they do work. Anything else I could try?

Comment: Make sure that `db2jcc.jar` (and the corresponding license jar) is in the classpath when you start the connector.

Comment: I do specify that in: `/etc/kafka/connect-standalone.properties`
By adding this line:
`plugin.path=/usr/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc/`

Output of ls:
`-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  3636386 Jun 21 12:04 db2jcc.jar`
`-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  4022185 Jun 21 12:04 db2jcc4.jar`

Comment: Your question/comments are confusing about which supplier's jdbc driver for Db2 you are using. Choose one of them, either Progress DataDirect or IBM. The class-names, driver file-names, and URL-format are different between the vendors, don't mix them.  For DataDirect the class name may be "com.ddtek.jdbc.db2.DB2Driver" and the filename delivering that class may be "db2.jar" (amongst others) and the URL format matches your original question. For IBM-supplied drivers, the class name is "com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver" and the filenames include db2jcc4.jar/db2jcc.jar/db2jcc_license_*.jar .

Comment: Thank you very much everyone. The jars we use for our sqoop jobs did the trick. They have the same name, but a different size. Apparently they were also downloaded from the IBM site. The Progress DataDirect stuff did not work at all, btw. Here is my final db2.properties file for my connector. Note the correct JDBC connection URL: name=test-db2-jdbc- connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector connection.url=jdbc:db2://db2-server:50000/test_bpm:schema=schemaName;user=db2admin;password=pwd-here-then-semicolon;

Answer (score 2):

I am the author of the tutorial that you mentioned, I just noticed this thread and I see that you are using IBM supplied DB2 driver(`db2cc.jar`) with DataDirect IBM DB2 connection string(`jdbc:datadirect:db2://db2-server:50000;User=db2admin;Password=pwd;Database=test_db`), which is why as soon as you changed the connection string to IBM supplied driver, you were able to connect properly.